# Is there a way to get a list of valid locales or check if locale is valid in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, locale

I need to validate some user input. From what I understand, "en-US" is a valid standard HTTP locale and "en_GB" is not. Is there a way to validate this?

Answer (score 1):

[Here's the spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.10) :

> The syntax and registry of HTTP language tags is the same as that
>   defined by RFC 1766 [1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.10). In summary, a language tag is composed of 1
>   or more parts: A primary language tag and a possibly empty series of
>   subtags:
>
> ```
>     language-tag  = primary-tag *( "-" subtag )
>     primary-tag   = 1*8ALPHA
>     subtag        = 1*8ALPHA
> ```
>
> [...]
>   where any two-letter primary-tag is an ISO-639 language abbreviation
>   and any two-letter initial subtag is an ISO-3166 country code. (The
>   last three tags above are not registered tags; all but the last are
>   examples of tags which could be registered in future.)

And [here are the country code](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/country_codes/country_names_and_code_elements.htm). Of course "GB" is in the list.

`en-GB` is perfectly OK, but `en_GB` isn't.